# Finding email addresses in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, address-book

often I find myself wanting to send an email from Thunderbird to someone I don't have the address. But I do have emails where this person's email is in the cc. So if I use the search bar in Thunderbird with the name of the person, I find all the emails where this person was involved.

What I can't figure out: How do I easily send an email to this person now? If I do the search, I can select an email where this person has been involved. But usually those emails have ~50 recipients. So it is quite tedious to manually have to go through the list of recipients and find the one address I need. Is there an easier way to find the email address? I remember from Outlook and also Windows Live Mail that it was quite straight forward.

Comment: It isn't clear what "straightforward" method you're referring to.  In any email application, you need to go to the specific person whose email address you want to copy.

Comment: Like in other applications I find the address from the search function and can click the wanted address in the results window.

Comment: To clarify a bit more: In Outlook 2016, after searching, I see also the names highlighted, and I can right-click them to send an email. In Thunderbird, I see the name only if it is in the beginning of the recipients, and if I right-click it is still not recognized as a contact. So I still need to find the email address from the recipient list.

Comment: You can look at the email headers to grab the address. Open one of the emails up that the person you are trying to get the email to is CC'd on. Double click to open that email, then click `more` at the top right, then `view source`. You can now scroll down to where the CC section is and the email should be displayed.

Comment: @Narzard: Yes, manually I can also find it in the list of recipients. But with 50+ recipients (sometimes the address doesn't resemble the name) it is a realllyyy tedious process.